# Extract text from JSON file

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley

I return a JSON file from a REST server. The JSON don't has to have this structe, I am only trying to make an example.

```
return Arrays.asList("Test", "This is a test");
```

the JSON result:

```
["Test","This is a test"]
```

I am using volley to request the JSON file. Every thnk is working fine but I don't know how to extract the values from the jsn

```
public void onResponse(Object response) {
        Log.i("test",response.toString());
```

but if I try something like

```
((JSONObject) response).getString ("File")
```

I get an error,

> can not cast file to JSONObject...

Answer (score 1):

Because This is a `JSONArray` not `JSONObject`. try to cast it to `JSONArray` instead

Try this

```
((JSONArray) response).getString ("File")
```